# Accessing Eclipse help through an external web browser

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've been working on adding help to eclipse RCP applications. I've understood how to add the required plugins and my custom help content associated with those.

Now, I want to access that same help content through a different browser (i.e. other than eclipse's inbuilt help system).

e.g. The link http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp shows the kind of arrangement I need. It provides the same user interface for Eclipse Help Documentation (as in eclipse's inbuilt help system) even when accessed through a different web browser.

I'm new to eclipse and facing some problems in getting it done. I've tried looking into the following Eclipse Help APIs but I'm not sure on how to use these:

1) org.eclipse.help.ui
2) org.eclipse.help.webapp

Can someone please guide me to a proper approach to accomplish this task. I'm presently working on Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2.

Comment: Read the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fua_help_setup.htm&cp=2_0_19_1_0) on setting up an information center or standalone help.

Comment: thanx @greg-449 ... it worked :)